# OneNote 2013 API to choose Pen (programatically)

Tags: winapi, ms-office, onenote

I read about the new OneNote Cloud API, but I am afraid that it's not what I am looking for.

I search a possibility to manipulate the pen in oneNote. So for example to be able to change the color or the Pen thickness from another program. Also it would be nice to click the "action back" and "Redo" buttons.

Do you knows if there is any possibility to do so? I am an experienced Java and C / C++ programer, but never did anything windows-specific, so this could be the reason why I do not know where I have to look.

Best regards! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Right now it's pretty vague.  Are you looking at the web api, or the COM api?

Answer (score 0):

The REST API won't help here, [there is some mention of support in the wishlist](https://onenotedev.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-api-feedback-suggestions?query=ink), but it doesn't appear to have a lot of traction.

I'm not 100% sure of your use case, you want to interact with the OneNote UI and change the user's pen setting so the next time they draw something then pen is what you've specified from your app?

If that's the case then the REST api won't help anyway as it's for manipulating content, you want to directly interact with OneNote and change the user's experience?

You could look at the [COM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680118%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and interact via the Windows desktop version though I can tell you now that the options for UI interaction are pretty minimal (e.g. show a quick filing dialogue, create new note window, dock note window)

You can interact with a user's basic ink content using `GetPageContent` and from the below example I ripped out of one of my pages it looks pretty simple to change the thickness, but maybe have a play with `GetBinaryPageContent` and you could alter colour too?

```
<one:OE author="Darren Beale" authorInitials="DB" lastModifiedBy="Darren Beale" lastModifiedByInitials="DB" creationTime="2014-05-11T07:42:59.000Z" lastModifiedTime="2014-05-11T07:42:59.000Z" objectID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{15}{B0}" alignment="left" quickStyleIndex="0">
      <one:T><![CDATA[]]></one:T>
    </one:OE>
  </one:Title>
  <one:InkDrawing lastModifiedTime="2014-05-11T07:43:17.000Z" objectID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{53}{B0}">
    <one:Position x="241.4976348876953" y="73.48818969726562" z="4" />
    <one:Size width="45.01417922973633" height="157.5212554931641" />
    <one:CallbackID callbackID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{53}{B0}" />
  </one:InkDrawing>
  <one:InkDrawing lastModifiedTime="2014-05-11T07:43:23.000Z" objectID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{63}{B0}">
    <one:Position x="209.9763793945312" y="108.7228317260742" z="5" />
    <one:Size width="42.77478790283203" height="116.3055114746094" />
    <one:CallbackID callbackID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{63}{B0}" />
  </one:InkDrawing>
  <one:InkDrawing lastModifiedTime="2014-05-11T07:43:14.000Z" objectID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{36}{B0}">
    <one:Position x="113.9952697753906" y="124.4834671020508" z="0" />
    <one:Size width="3.770078659057617" height="145.5307006835937" />
    <one:CallbackID callbackID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{36}{B0}" />
  </one:InkDrawing>
  <one:InkDrawing lastModifiedTime="2014-05-11T07:43:15.000Z" objectID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{43}{B0}">
    <one:Position x="149.9952697753906" y="163.4881896972656" z="2" />
    <one:Size width="1.530704498291016" height="102.7842559814453" />
    <one:CallbackID callbackID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{43}{B0}" />
  </one:InkDrawing>
  <one:InkDrawing lastModifiedTime="2014-05-11T07:43:16.000Z" objectID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{48}{B0}">
    <one:Position x="176.2440948486328" y="171.0" z="3" />
    <one:Size width="51.76062393188476" height="121.5212478637695" />
    <one:CallbackID callbackID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{48}{B0}" />
  </one:InkDrawing>
  <one:InkDrawing lastModifiedTime="2014-05-11T07:43:26.000Z" objectID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{68}{B0}">
    <one:Position x="292.492919921875" y="180.7228240966797" z="6" />
    <one:Size width="76.50707244873047" height="40.53543090820312" />
    <one:CallbackID callbackID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{68}{B0}" />
  </one:InkDrawing>
  <one:InkDrawing lastModifiedTime="2014-05-11T07:43:14.000Z" objectID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{38}{B0}">
    <one:Position x="98.97164916992187" y="197.2488098144531" z="1" />
    <one:Size width="52.55432891845703" height="51.02363204956054" />
    <one:CallbackID callbackID="{F8158129-96AB-4D65-80B0-3AF7DE849E62}{38}{B0}" />
  </one:InkDrawing>
```

Comment: Hi Darren. 
Thank you for you reply! After looking at you answer and even more googling, i fear that it is way too complex or time-consuming, in relation to what I wanted to do.

So I thank you for your reply, but I think I am not going to realice this project :(